# How to multiply value from hashes in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just start to study ruby. I got a simple question. I have my hash 
`exchange_rate = ["usd" => 1, "eur" => 1.2, "gbp" => 1.3]`
So what I want to do, I wan make a script what will be calculate the write rate.
For Example, if I want to know USD rate for 20EUR, script will show me, 
`your exchange rate is 24USD`

This is my code

```
class ExchangeRate
  def initialize (exchange_amount_id)
    @exchange_amount = exchange_amount_id
  end

  exchange_rate = ["usd" => 1, "eur" => 1.2, "gbp" => 1.3]

  def exchange ()
  end 

  classob = ExhangeRate.new(20)
  classob.exchange()
  end
end
```

But still I want to know how to make this calculations, for showing the write rate for different currencies

Comment: _Sidenote:_ one should **never ever** use floats for money calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ExchangeRate
  def initialize (rate)
    @rate = rate
  end

  def exchange(from, to, value)
    @rate.fetch(from) / @rate.fetch(to) * value
  end
end

rate = { usd: 1, eur: 1.2, gbp: 1.3}
money = ExchangeRate.new(rate)
puts money.exchange(:eur, :usd, 20)
# you will get 24
```

note: **fetch** will find value inside hash with given key

Answer (score 1):

I think you could make this class as service. And you don't need to create new objects of it. Instead just make single class .call method.

```
class RateExchanger
  EXCHANGE_RATES = {
      usd: 1,
      eur: 1.2,
      gbp: 1.3
  }.freeze

  def self.call(to:, value:, from: :usd)
    (value / EXCHANGE_RATES[from] * EXCHANGE_RATES[to]).round(2)
  end
end

RateExchanger.call(to: :gbp, value: 100, from: :eur)
```

Comment: Since this has no instances and no state, it could be a Module instead of a Class (`module RateExchanger`).